# Second Spark thrift Server without Kerberos

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, thrift

I have a kerberized HDP 2.5 Cluster with a running Spark Thrift Server (Spark 1.6.2).
A colleague would like to connect to the thrift server with a client that doesn't support passing Kerberos parameters.

Is it possible to start on another node a second thrift server that doesn't need kerberos for authentication?

Comment: In short, you want a way to bypass security procedures? Just go to your CSO's office and tell him/her that you need an unsecure Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Well, it's only a demo cluster and we want to prepare a show case.

Comment: BTW, which kind of Hive Thrift client are you talking about? Did you check that there was indeed no way to configure Kerberos auth, or no alternative?

Comment: It' a spark thrift server not hive. The cluster is kerberized and hive can be reached over JDBC/ODBC only with a kerberos ticket or over the knox gateway (no ticket needed).

Comment: For Spark thrift there isn't a knox service, the client software doesn't support kerberos when configuring the connection.

Comment: ah ok, the client is tableau. Tableau has a "hive" source type and a "sparkSQL" source type. The mask to configure a sparksql connection doesn't provide any krb parameters. On the other hand, the setup of a connection to hive over knox worked well

Comment: From the Horton documentation, _"The Spark Thrift Server is a variant of HiveServer2, so you can use many of the same settings"_ >> did you try to connect Tableau to Spark using "hive" connector? Did you try to set up a second "HS2" port in Knox, pointing to the Spark service?  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/config-sts.html  and https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_spark-component-guide/content/access-jdbc.html etc.

Comment: I tried with an additional service in Knox copying the hive one, but there is an issue between knox and spark thrift.

Comment: Regarding using the hive ODBC from Tableau to Spark Thrift, we have problems with the krb ticket on windows. We use the MIT krb5 client because the Domain used for cluster kerberization is not the same one as the company default. We successfully get a ticket with kinit on Win, but both Hive and spark thrift tell that they miss the ticket. Only hive through knox works at the moment

Comment: In any case, in the Horton Community I found an article telling that Spark Thrift through Knox is not supported. If "not supported" = "it doesn't work" is a matter of try yourself activity. I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: _"MIT Kerberos ... get a ticket with kinit"_ > which one? the `kinit.exe` bundled with MIT Kerberos, or the `kinit.exe` bundled with Java? They don't use the same default `KRB5CCNAME` protocol ("API:" for MIT, "FILE:..." for Java). Also, did you set up the ODBC driver to use GSSAPI -- instead of the standard SSPI that allows Windows SSO? And did you set up the `KRB5CCNAME` to use?

Comment: _"the hive ODBC from Tableau"_ > is that the shitty driver from DataDirect that does not properly work with Kerberos and/or SSL and/or High Availability via ZK?!? Just install a proper Hive ODBC driver, from Horton or Cloudera, then create a DSN to your Hive or Spark service, and plug Tableau on that "generic" DSN. It will try do do silly things (such as creating a transactional temp table in `default` database) and hence be even slower that is usual with Tableau, but it will work. Did that with Horton in 2015 (custom KDC) and with Cloudera last month (Active Directory + SSO).